# Connecting to the internet using my WLAN in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, internet-connection, wireless-networking

Whenever I boot into Ubuntu it detects the local networks perfectly, but after selecting my network and typing in the correct password for WEP2 it can't connect to the internet.

What's the problem?

I'm using a D-Link DWL-G122 USB dongle.

Comment: Hi Julian, sorry but this isn't a programming related question.

Your question would most likely be better placed over at: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Start off and see if You've been given an IP address from the network.
so in the terminal :

```
$ifconfig
```

Should return something like...

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:67:15:f6:52  
      inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::230:67ff:fe15:f652/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:118167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:82452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:141978918 (141.9 MB)  TX bytes:9949543 (9.9 MB)
      Interrupt:28 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:106321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:106321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:18467947 (18.4 MB)  TX bytes:18467947 (18.4 MB)
```

except your's should say 'wlan0' or something similar instead of 'eth0'

Then if thats ok, check and see if you've been assigned DNS correctly.

```
$route
```

which should say

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

That 'default' line is whats important.

If either of these steps don't make sense, try doing

```
$dhclient <NAME OF YOUR INTERFACE LIKE WLAN0 ETC>
```

If you're unsure about any of the outputs of the above commands, edit your question to include them.

Answer (score -1):

Install Wireshark to examine the network traffic. You might be able to see error text that gives a clue about the problem.

Comment: -1 kind of a rigorous step to be taking at a first attempt.

Comment: Nobody had responded in over a month, so I assumed that a "rigorous step" would be appropriate.

Downvoting a response just because you don't like the answer doesn't exactly encourage participation.